# ActiveStorage can't move file to S3 - Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

## The (Simple) Problem

I'm attempting a simple `heroku run rake db:seeds`. It attempts to use Active Storage to move few images from `app/assets/images` into to AWS S3.

Here's a portion that fails:

```rb
user = User.last
file_name = "steve.png"
file_path = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "seeds")
user.user_primary_image.attach(io: File.open(file_path + file_name), filename: file_name)
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.104.3/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:17:in `call'
```

## What I know so far

1. `rake db:seeds` run locally with no problems
2. These are all set correctly:

```rb
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
ENV['AWS_REGION']
ENV['S3_BUCKET']
```

3. The IAM for the bucket has a policy which has:

- allowed actions: `All S3 actions (s3:*)`
- a resource ARN of the bucket name

4. The bucket has the following CORS:
   (`example` is replaced with the actual domain)

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://www.example.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

That's all so far, but I can't think of anything else to try to debug this...

#### UPDATE

I created a new IAM with S3 Full Access (every permission on every bucket), and it works. So the trouble is with the more refined IAM, which of course must be implemented (it would not be smart to leave it wide open).

So I took the working implementation, then added write, list and read permissions, and narrowed to one bucket (the one it needs), and now I reproduce the error:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.104.3/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:17:in `call'
```

So I know the error has something to do with either the permissions or the resource. I cannot tell what. Perhaps a bug in S3?

#### UPDATE 2

With all permissions, simply limiting S3 access to one resource (i.e. one bucket) causes the process to go from working to not working. Here is the bucket setting:

[image]

and `accesspoint`, `job`, `object`, and `storagelensconfig` are all left unchanged.

Comment: Is it possible the credentials just aren't getting passed in relation to the seed file?  Do any other uploads work when initiated by the seed file?

Comment: @RockwellRice please see the update section. Basically if I relax the policy on the IAM, it works, and when I set it sensibly (i.e. limit it to just read, write, and list permissions on my_bucket), then it doesn't work. Very weird. But I think because it works with S3FullAccess means it's not a problem with creds. I.e. it *must* be a problem with the IAM policy settings.

Comment: @RockwellRice but to specifically answer your question, yep everything works when I have the IAM policy wide open (all the uploads in seeds work), but when the IAM policy is set sensibly nothing works - it errors on the first `user.image.attach(....)`

Answer (score 3):

So after hours of toggling and testing, trying to narrow down which particular setting was causing it to work and not work, I finally arrived at this policy being just enough to work with Active Storage, and it's limited to one bucket (i.e. not just giving access to everything in S3):

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Just replace `mybucket` with your bucket name in both of the two places.

I found it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)